# Is the “amalgamation” of an enumerated infinite collection of absolutely normal real numbers always absolutely normal?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $S$ denote an enumerated infinite collection of *absolutely normal* (i.e. normal in all integer bases greater than or equal to $2$) real numbers (with no repetitions) such that any natural number corresponds to a unique element of $S$.

Let $F(S)$ denote a real number such that $0 < F(S) < 1$ and each $(2^x \times (2y + 1) - 1)$-th bit of the base-$2$ representation of the fractional part of $F(S)$ is equal to an $y$-th bit of the base-$2$ representation of the fractional part of an $x$-th element of $S$.

Question: does there exist an example of $S$ such that the corresponding $F(S)$ is **not** absolutely normal? If yes (or no), is it possible to prove this?

This question is not about an explicit example of $S$ satisfying the described property, it is only about the *existence* of such $S$ (and provability of the existence).

Comment: I expect the answer to the question in the title to be no (and to the one in the body to be yes). Let $s=0.s_1s_2s_3...$ be absolutely normal. Then $s'=0.s_2s_4s_6...$ will again be normal base $2$, and for generic $s$ it should be absolutely normal, but I don't know how to prove it formally. At any rate if $S$ has $s$ as its zeroth element and $s'$ as its first, then $F(S)$ won't be normal, since its $4k+1$st and $4k+2$nd bits will always match.

Comment: @Wojowu That's almost right, except that "generic" should be "random" - [generic reals are far from normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820145/true-random-number-set/3820229#3820229).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Apologies, I have never seen "generic" used in the sense of comeager (which I think is what you are implying this term means).

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, that's the standard usage in logic at least; I was under the impression that that was standard elsewhere, but I could be wrong.